# `apt update` results in consistent "Failed to Fetch" errors for different apt sources

Tags: apt, package-management

After a recent update from Bionic-based Pop OS! 18.04 to Cosmic-based Pop OS! 18.10, executing `apt update` always results in *Failed to Fetch .... Temporary failure resolving* errors for few sites.  Interestingly,

1. failing apt sources vary from each execution of `apt update`,
2. URLs of failed apt source can be successfully accessed via a browser while or after `apt update` executes, and
3. all of the failures are associated with *InRelease* files.

Any idea what might be messed up?

#### Edit1

**Time**: Thu Mar 28 12:04:42 CDT 2019

**Output**:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/cosmic/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.canonical.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://apt.pop-os.org/proprietary/dists/cosmic/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'apt.pop-os.org'
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/cosmic-security/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'security.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch https://packagecloud.io/AtomEditor/atom/any/dists/any/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'packagecloud.io'
W: Failed to fetch https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com/dists/cosmic/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://downloads.skewed.de/apt/cosmic/dists/cosmic/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'downloads.skewed.de'
W: Failed to fetch https://deb.nodesource.com/node_10.x/dists/cosmic/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'deb.nodesource.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://repository.spotify.com/dists/stable/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'repository.spotify.com'
W: Failed to fetch https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian/dists/cosmic/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'download.virtualbox.org'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

**Time**: Thu Mar 28 12:08:43 CDT 2019

**Output**:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/cosmic/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://apt.pop-os.org/proprietary/dists/cosmic/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'apt.pop-os.org'
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/alexlarsson/flatpak/ubuntu/dists/cosmic/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'ppa.launchpad.net'
W: Failed to fetch https://packagecloud.io/AtomEditor/atom/any/dists/any/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'packagecloud.io'
W: Failed to fetch https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com/dists/cosmic/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com'
W: Failed to fetch https://storage.googleapis.com/download.dartlang.org/linux/debian/dists/stable/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'storage.googleapis.com'
W: Failed to fetch https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/dists/cosmic/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'download.docker.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://binaries.erlang-solutions.com/debian/dists/cosmic/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'binaries.erlang-solutions.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu/dists/cosmic/InRelease  Could not connect to ppa.launchpad.net:80 (91.189.95.83), connection timed out [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
W: Failed to fetch https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/18.10/prod/dists/cosmic/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'packages.microsoft.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/plt/racket/ubuntu/dists/cosmic/InRelease  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http: [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/swi-prolog/stable/ubuntu/dists/cosmic/InRelease  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http: [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/system76-dev/stable/ubuntu/dists/cosmic/InRelease  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http: [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/system76/pop/ubuntu/dists/cosmic/InRelease  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http: [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
W: Failed to fetch https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian/dists/cosmic/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'download.virtualbox.org'
W: Failed to fetch http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode/dists/stable/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'packages.microsoft.com'
W: Failed to fetch https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/dists/stable/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'dl.yarnpkg.com'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Barring `https://storage.googleapis.com/download.dartlang.org/linux/debian/dists/stable/InRelease`, every URL was reachable via the browser immediately after the execution of the command.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us your `sources.list` and the exact error messages you are receiving.

Comment: I have added the output from two executions that were 4 minutes apart.

Comment: @GAD3R why do you think this is a DNS issue when I am able to access all of the failed source URLs via a browser?  Also, what should I add to which YAML file in `/etc/netplan`?  More details would be helpful.